# Install Tezos from source - Error

Tags: node

I want to install Tezos from source with the way to build the binaries from the source code with the OPAM source package manager for OCaml. I want to install it on my WSL Ubuntu.
I am following the guide on Opentezos:
https://opentezos.com/deploy-a-node/installation/

First I install OPAM package manager:

```
bash -c "sh <(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ocaml/opam/master/shell/install.sh)"
```

This is a success and gives me following output:

```
## Downloading opam 2.1.4 for linux on x86_64...
## Downloaded.
## Where should it be installed ? [/usr/local/bin]
Write access to /usr/local/bin required, using 'sudo'.
Command: install -m 755 /tmp/opam-2.1.4-x86_64-linux /usr/local/bin/opam
[sudo] password for hakim:
## opam 2.1.4 installed to /usr/local/bin
## Run this script again with '--restore ' to revert.
```

Then I enter the next command from the tutorial:

```
opam init --bare
```

But here I get the following error:

```
No configuration file found, using built-in defaults.
Checking for available remotes: rsync and local, git.
  - you won't be able to use mercurial repositories unless you install the hg command on your system.
  - you won't be able to use darcs repositories unless you install the darcs command on your system.

[ERROR] Missing dependencies -- the following commands are required for opam to operate:
  - unzip
  - bwrap: Sandboxing tool bwrap was not found. You should install 'bubblewrap'. See
    https://opam.ocaml.org/doc/FAQ.html#Why-does-opam-require-bwrap.
```

The Opentezos docs say I can ignore a switch error. Is this what the docs mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installation instructions for Opam are given here: https://opam.ocaml.org/doc/Install.html. In particular, the recommended way to install Opam on Ubuntu is to use a ppa, see https://opam.ocaml.org/doc/Install.html#Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you, it seems there are problems to install on WSL. I will setup a dedicated VM with Ubuntu for it as its not that easy to do on WSL